# javascript Number validations

Tags: javascript

I  need to check if a number entered contain

1.more than two digit after decimal

2.decimal at first place (ex:.2345)

3.decimal at last place (ex:2345.)

How to do this using javascript.

Comment: How can a NUMBER have a decimal at the front and end? I think your meant to ask about strings.

Comment: Is this part of form validation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
len = number.length;
pos = number.indexOf('.');

if (pos == 0)
{
  //decimal is at first place
}
if (pos == len - 1)
{
  //decimal is at last place
}
if (pos == len - 3)
{
  //more than two digit after decimal
}
```

Comment: `.length` is a property, not a method. Nice and fast apprach, however.

Comment: Probably should use else...if so as to not test multiple times.

Comment: use `pos < len - 3`. Now it can have only 2 decimals.

Answer (score 2):

```
var reg = /\d+(?:\.\d{2,})?/;

if ( reg.test(number) )
    alert('Correct format!');
```

Not sure whether you'd allow decimals only (i.e. without the period) but if, that regexp should be sufficient.

Good luck.

Comment: Why would he need luck? Is your code that fragile? ;) +1 for the correct answer.

Comment: Good luck with his effort to validate user input, that is.

Comment: You're right about that. One needs to be very careful with user input.

Answer (score 1):

```
function check_number(number) {
    var my_number = String(number);
    var place = my_number.indexOf(".");
    if(place == 0) return "first";
    else if(place == (my_number.length - 1)) return "last";
    else if(place == (my_number.length - 3)) return "third to last";
}
```

Comment: @Shakti Singh, you beat me to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
var number = "3.21";
if(/[0-9]{1,}\.[0-9]{2,}/.test(number)) {
  //valid
}
```

Comment: I think `number` should be a string here. Besides that, `.test()` is a method of the `RegExp` object. You should use `.match()` or modify your code so that your regular expression is in front.

Comment: Ah yes, thanks for pointing that out. Can you only pass a regex on strings in js?

Comment: I am not sure if i understand what you mean, but `.match()` is a method of `String`. You can use it to do it the other way around: `"some string".match(/some/)`

Comment: Does it matter? Is match better compared to test?